# Magento 2: Disable redirection to product page if requested quantity is not available on add to cart function

Tags: magento2, inventory, catalog

On catalog category page, when I add add any product to cart and the requested quantity is not available, it redirects to product page and shows error message there.
[Error message image on product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgzKC.png)

What I want is to display error message while staying on the same page, instead of opening the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Customization on theme is required for this feature.

And you should hide or disable add to cart button for out of stock product for better UX instead of popup warning message when action is not allowed.

For workaround, you can hide out of stock product at category page but modify the following configuration

```
System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Display out of stock product
```